# how does the linux kernel avoid deadlocks?

Tags: concurrency, linux-kernel, deadlock

How does the linux kernel avoids deadlocks in user processes? Does it have a built-in mechanism that prevents them, or one that recognizes and kills them?

And, is there anything similar for kernel programming?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The kernel does not avoid deadlocks of user-space locks (because often it doesn't even know about them).

Deadlocks of kernel locks are avoided by writing code that is correct.
This is greatly helped by [lockdep](http://lwn.net/Articles/185666/), which can prove the correctness of locking operations.

(The lockdep code has been [ported](http://lwn.net/Articles/536363/) to user space, but it helps only for programs that bother to use it.)